# moq and parameters matching

Tags: c#, moq

I'm struggeling with using moq and validating parameters passed to the methods of mocked interface. I have a code like:

```
MockRepository mockRepository = new MockRepository(MockBehavior.Default);

Mock<IConfigurationUpdater> workerInstanceMock = mockRepository.Create<IConfigurationUpdater>();
Mock<IConfiguration> configurationMock = mockRepository.Create<IConfiguration>();

configurationMock.Setup(t => t.Folder).Returns("Folder");
configurationMock.Setup(t => t.FileName).Returns("FileName");

workerInstanceMock
    .Setup(
          x => x.DoSomeWork(
                It.Is<string>(
                  t => t == Path.Combine(configurationMock.Object.Folder, configurationMock.Object.FileName))))
    .Verifiable("DoSomeWork not properly called");

    mockRepository.VerifyAll();
```

The problem is that inside the lambda expresion generated for "It.Is", all properties of configurationMock (which were setup previously) are null. (if I would take that "Path.Combine" into a string, it would all work just fine).
In this exact case, the "Path.Combine" is failing because it received null parameters.

How should I properly use mocks and validate that my interface is called with the correct parameters.

Thanks,
florin

Comment: Note that only usign the Path.Combine gets this behaviour as it seems that it runs the lamba expression in another context.
Using "It.Is<string>(t => t == savConfigurationMock.Object.LiveUpdateFolder + "\\" + savConfigurationMock.Object.LiveUpdateMergeConfigFile)" or putting it in a property works just file.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use moq properties that will automatically start tracking its value (Stubs).

Instead of:

```
configurationMock.Setup(t => t.Folder).Returns("Folder");
configurationMock.Setup(t => t.FileName).Returns("FileName");
```

you can use

```
configurationMock.SetupProperty(t => t.Folder, "Folder");
configurationMock.SetupProperty(t => t.FileName, "FileName");
```

and then access the property as you did:

```
configurationMock.Object.Folder
```

More on moq properties can be found here: http://code.google.com/p/moq/wiki/QuickStart#Properties

Comment: Does not work, it has the same behaviour: inside the lambda (It.Is...), the properties return null.

Comment: Perhaps this is a silly question but I will ask: Folder and FileName are declared as properties in the IConfiguration interface? I mean with the get; and set; syntax?

Comment: Yes (and IConfiguration is indeed an iterface not a class :) ). Initially they had only getter, then while tried your sugestion also added a setter (SetupProperty requires a setter to create the stub).

Comment: It's weird, I try several variations of the code and it didn't work (as expected :p). The only way I found to make it work is accessing to the Folder and FileName properties outside the lambda expression and store them in two variables, check it here: [link](http://pastebin.com/0zvT2eEq).

Comment: I've added a bug to moq issue tracking, http://code.google.com/p/moq/issues/detail?id=317

Comment: Great! This is an interesting issue, I'll hope they fix it, or at least give some clues to find where the error is.